# PostgreSQL join performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have two tables in a PostgreSQL 9.3 database:

> TableA(ID numeric, VALUE numeric(5,4)) - about 1milion records.
>
> TableB(ID numeric, field2 .. fieldN) - about 5milion records.

I'm trying to do a simple JOIN between TableA&TableB by ID field, filtering by field VALUE.
Although VALUE can have 4 decimals, the filter applied can have only two decimals.

My SQL looks like this (0.45 is the filter parameter ranging from 0.00 to 1.00):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.VALUE, B.a_lot_of_fields_here
FROM TableA A, TableB B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
and A.VALUE >= 0.45
```

Both IDs (A.ID, B.ID) are PK. I'm wondering if I can do something to speed up more the SQL. Any suggestions?

This is the query explain plan:

```
"Hash Join  (cost=22205.73..310550.04 rows=1167395 width=105)"
"  Hash Cond: ((a.id)::text = (b.id)::text)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on tablea a  (cost=0.00..140163.94 rows=3557794 width=80)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=17404.18..17404.18 rows=248284 width=25)"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tableb b  (cost=4652.63..17404.18 rows=248284 width=25)"
"              Recheck Cond: (value >= 0.1)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_test  (cost=0.00..4590.56 rows=248284 width=0)"
"                    Index Cond: (value >= 0.1)"
```

And the one with ANALYZE/BUFFERS

```
"Hash Join  (cost=22205.73..315312.78 rows=1398289 width=109) (actual time=2065.165..12794.984 rows=1267024 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: ((a.id)::text = (b.id)::text)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=177 read=71080 written=47217, temp read=47454 written=47424"
"  ->  Seq Scan on tablea a  (cost=0.00..107631.74 rows=4261474 width=84) (actual time=0.014..2815.098 rows=3557794 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=175 read=64842 written=43965"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=17404.18..17404.18 rows=248284 width=25) (actual time=2047.615..2047.615 rows=248617 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 2048  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 901kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=6238 written=3252, temp written=1319"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tableb b  (cost=4652.63..17404.18 rows=248284 width=25) (actual time=491.395..1914.202 rows=248617 loops=1)"
"              Recheck Cond: (value >= 0.1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=2 read=6238 written=3252"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_test  (cost=0.00..4590.56 rows=248284 width=0) (actual time=448.286..448.286 rows=248617 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (value >= 0.1)"
"                    Buffers: shared read=682"
"Total runtime: 12905.306 ms"
```

[(On explain.depesz.com)](http://explain.depesz.com/s/tii)

Now I'm working on A.ID and B.ID fields: they are text fields... I'm going to codify the text into integers to see how much performance gain is possible with this approach.

Postgres configuration stuff:

I looked in the postresql.conf. I have all parameters with default value :( -I haven't got the knowledge to tune them-. Just one is edited (by a sysadmin):

```
shared_buffers = 128MB
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: An index on `TableA.Value`, would help. Since `TableB.ID` is the clustered index anyway you won't need any changes to this table.

Comment: Both tables have indexes on the IDs (they are PKs). The join applying a filter of 0.1, returning 1.250.000 records costs about 9secs. Looks like a improvable time?

Comment: I have created the index as suggested by GarethD but nothing has improved :(

Comment: Can you show the query plan?

Comment: Yeah, I already posted the plan in the question

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.

Comment: Andy, I posted table definitions in the question. Also row counts (1 milion, 5 milion). Indexes: the PK ones. What else do you want?

Comment: Can you show the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...`?

Comment: @fiopo: You posted a paraphrase of your table definitions and indexes.  But it's possible you didn't do them right, and we might see other things in your table that are problematic.  That's why I suggest that you post the full table & index definitions.

Comment: The query plan indicates that there are `3557794` rows in table A - way more than the stated 1 million.

Comment: The problem might be in the postgres server configuration. Can you show your config files? Specifically the configuration of shared work memory.

Comment: The 3557794 rows are the ones for the around 5milion table. Tomorrow I will post the shared working memory. What do you think about the execution time? 9seconds is way too much or not?

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing if results change with `random_page_cost = 1.1` and `effective_cache_size` set correctly for your system.

Comment: effective_cache_size set to 1024MB has speeded up a lot sequential query executions. It seems that indexes are not fitting with its default value (128Mb) Thx a lot Craig, it's a step forward in performance (although using a lot more memory).

Answer (score 0):

It the amount or records with `A.VALUE >= 0.45` is relatively small (say less than 5% of the total count) the index on `A.VALUE` could speed up the query. Also a composite index on `(A.VALUE, A.ID)` could allow index only scan on table A.